# joomla htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

At present my joomla urls are showing up like http://www.website.com/index.php/gallery

instead of http://www.website.com/gallery.php

So I've went into the global configurations section... to the right hand side there is a panel - I Have search engine friendly URL's turned ON...

Underneath that is the option to Use URL rewriting - with a warning to use this feature htaccess.txt must be renamed to .htaccess --- so at present it is off - Should this be on? If so the problem is that on my server there is already a .htaccess file

the contents are:

```
# -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName prestige-car-valeting.com
AuthUserFile /home/prestig1/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/prestig1/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp
```

then there is the htaccess.txt file which contains alot of

```
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##
```

so obviously when i try to rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess it pops up that such a file already exists...

any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the code in your htaccess.txt file and add it to your existing .htaccess file.

That's really all you need to do. Your search engine friendly URLs are not going to work unless the appropriate entries are made to .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Joomla do you use?
You will need .htaccess for URL rewriting. So it must be on.
Can you delete the existing one and copy an new .htaccess file from Joomla in youre website directory? But first you need to turn the option off -> then copy the new .htaccess file and then turn the option back on.

Answer (score 0):

Shyantanu is correct, you just need to copy one into the other.

Specifically, I would add the contents of the Joomla htaccess.txt file *after* the contents in your already existing .htaccess file. This is because your existing file contains directives to restrict access, and generally this should take place before any other directives are processed (no point in rewriting a URL if you're not supposed to access it!).

Answer (score 0):

You may notice that cpanel wont show the existing .htaccess file only the htacces.txt but as you say it wont allow you to rename as one already exists..

I simply use an ftp program such as filezilla or cuteftp and once in my sites ftp i can see the .htacess file fine. I then delete the current one and use the htaccess.txt as my default.